SwapRouter02 calling exactInputSingle: execution reverted (base chain)
i'm trying to send a function via ethers.js to BASE chain:
config.SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481";
const ABI = require("@uniswap/swap-router-contracts/artifacts/contracts/SwapRouter02.sol/SwapRouter02.json");

const r = new ethers.Contract(config.SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, ABI.abi, wallet);
let tx = await r.callStatic.exactInputSingle({
        tokenIn: "0xfEA9DcDc9E23a9068bF557AD5b186675C61d33eA",
        tokenOut: "0x72499bddb67f4ca150e1f522ca82c87bc9fb18c8",
        fee: 0,
        recipient: wallet.address,
        amountIn: 1,
        amountOutMinimum: 0,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
    }, {
        gasLimit: 850000,
        gasPrice: 200000000
    });

It gives me that error:
body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":44,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}}',
requestBody: '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"gas":"0xcf850","gasPrice":"0xbebc200","from":"0x7975f1168c5bfe16857f428c8a85772d6719a679","to":"0x2626664c2603336e57b271c5c0b26f421741e481","data":"0x04e45aaf000000000000000000000000fea9dcdc9e23a9068bf557ad5b186675c61d33ea00000000000000000000000072499bddb67f4ca150e1f522ca82c87bc9fb18c80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb80000000000000000000000007975f1168c5bfe16857f428c8a85772d6719a679000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"latest"],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}'

I really don't know what the problem is.
When i'm trying without .callStatic, it give me a transaction hash, but there is no transaction on chain (basescan.org)

Without .callStatic it gave you a transaction hash that didn't appear on explorer and what happened when you used .callStatic ?

Hey, why is fee 0, there won't be a pool with those two tokens and zero fee, so that shouldn't work. What fee does the pool you are trying to swap on have? Amount in looks too small, how is it supposed to swap 0.000000000000000001 for anything?.

I tried different values, and set a fee to 3000, now i got it work. But sometimes it send transaction to "Wrapped ETH", and sometimes it sends transaction to swaprouter02 contract, and it success. The last problem is, i can't get it to always send swaprouter02 contract image
